# Why is $0\cdot x$ defined in fields even though $F\setminus\{0\}$ is the set for multiplication

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, finite-fields

I am somewhat confused about a definition thing about fields. It says that $\otimes$ is defined on $F \setminus \{0\}$, but in all tables I find, the zero row and column do have entries. From $\otimes$ beig defined for $F \setminus \{0\}$ I would expect the $0$ element to not occur in multiplication tables. Consider these tables: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_field#Field_with_four_elements

Why is $0$ defined in the multiplication table or conversely if $0$ is defined for multiplication why does it say in the definition that $\otimes$ is defined on $F \setminus \{0\}$?

Comment: Multiplication *is* defined on all of $F$.

Comment: (1) What $\;\otimes\;$ do you mean? Product in the field? Call it that, as $\;\otimes\;$ is way another thing. (2) What columns and rows are you talking about? Of what? Try to be clearer with your questions.

Comment: With $\otimes$ I mean the abstract multiplication. And I am referring to the row and column of the $0$ in the multiplication table in he article I linked.

Comment: Use dot not $\otimes$

Comment: You take the final part as the definition, which it is not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are wrong, multiplication is defined on whole $F$. You are confusing it with existence of inverses for multiplication. They exist on $F\setminus\{0\}$, i.e. all elements of $F$ are invertible with respect to multiplication except $0$. This does not mean that multiplication with $0$ is not defined, it means that *division* with $0$ is not defined! One not only has mulitplication with $0$, from distributivity you have:
$$0\cdot x = (0+0)\cdot x = 0\cdot x + 0\cdot x\implies 0\cdot x = 0$$ for all $x\in F$.

Comment: Ok I see. But then is the definition (from wiki on fields) ´A field is therefore an algebraic structure consisting of two abelian groups: F under +, −, and 0; F ∖ {0} under ·, −1, and 1, with 0 ≠ 1, with · distributing over +´ incomplete? Because for me that means that multiplication is not defined on F... So, is that definition incomplete or do I misunderstand it, and if so, where does it say or imply that multiplication is in fact defined? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field_(mathematics)

Comment: @user3578468, that is not a definition of a field. The statement is necessary, but not sufficient for the reason you noticed: multiplication with $0$ is undefined. All you have to do is find two abelian groups: $F$ and $F\setminus\{0\}$ such that $F$ is not a field.

Answer (score 1):

Multiplication *is* defined on all of $F$. What isn't true is that $F$ with multiplication is a group (however $F\setminus \{0\}$ is).